# Data Mapping object with lazy loaded properties

Tags: design, design-patterns, architecture, software

let's imagine we have an object User with a property of type Profile that can be accessed by the method getProfile and since we don't need the User's profile for every operation we decided to lazy load the User's Profile. But now, what happens when we decide to update the User object in the database using it's DataMapper? Using the most simple approach would make the User object load the Profile and then save it to database.But it is easy to see that loading an object from the database just to save it again it's useless. What would be a good design choice for this situation?

Comment: UPDATE User Set soleFieldToBeUpdated = newValue WHERE UserID = desiredUserID.

Comment: Sorry @RobertHarvey, could you explain further?

Comment: It's a SQL command that only modifies the desired field.

Comment: How the query fits into the design solution?

Comment: It only modifies the desired field.

Comment: But if the Profile is loaded the mapper should update it too since it was probably changed in some way. How can the data mapper find out if this happened?

Comment: Wasn't it your premise in your question that the Profile was *not* loaded yet?

Comment: No, what I meant was that the Profile is lazy loaded so there will be situations that the Profile is loaded and others that it won't be.How can the User's data mapper distinguish from this two situations? I'm thinking that maybe I could say that User implements LazyLoader that has a method getLazyLoadingTracker that returns a LazyLoadingTracker object. The LazyLoadingTracker is an object that classes outside the User can "ask" for information about the loading process. What do you think?